# Change the Value of h1 Element within a Form with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

I have two forms on an HTML5 page. Each form has a name and an id. The second form has an h1 element, which also has a name and an id. How do I change the text of this h1 element on the second form using plain JavaScript?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Try:

```
document.getElementById("yourH1_element_Id").innerHTML = "yourTextHere";
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use this: `document.getElementById('h1_id').innerHTML = 'the new text';`

Answer (score 5):

```
document.getElementById("myh1id").innerHTML = "my text"
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `textContent` property as a best practice. The `innerHTML` property changes everything inbetween the `h1` tags, which could mean that if there was something else between the `h1` tags, like an emphasis or strong tag it would disappear. `textContent` would only change the text of the header. It's probably not a big deal for your `h1` but it may make a difference knowing the difference in the future.

```
document.getElementById('h1_id').textContent = 'h1 content';
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following:

```
document.getElementById("your_h1_id").innerHTML = "your new text here"
```

Comment: Why the repeated answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this

```
document.querySelector('yourId').innerHTML = 'Content';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with regular JavaScript this way:

```
document.getElementById('h1_id').innerHTML = 'h1 content here';
```

Here is the doc for [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and the [innerHTML property](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/innertHTML).

The `innerHTML` property description:

> A DOMString containing the HTML serialization of the element's descendants. Setting the value of innerHTML removes all of the element's descendants and replaces them with nodes constructed by parsing the HTML given in the string htmlString.