# How can I get answer on same page instead of an alert?

Tags: javascript

I want a button that every time you click it it gives you a different answer(Animals, Movies or TV Shows, and so on), the thing is I have a button (that I found online, I'm new at coding) but that button gives me the answer in a little alert box, is there a way to make it give me the answer below the button? Here's the code I found:

```
var words = ['Animals', 'Movies', 'TV Shows'];

function randomAlert() {


  var alertIndex;


  var randomValue = Math.random();


  if (randomValue < 0.5) {
    alertIndex = 0;
  }


  else if(randomValue < 0.8) {
    alertIndex = 1;
  }


  else {
    alertIndex = 2;
  }

  alert(words[alertIndex]).innerHTML
}
```

Comment: Just get rid of alert and insert text to document, also the `innerHTML` should be inside the function call

Comment: I take it that there's an HTML document that the script is running on? If so, there's a nice answer to your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529327/change-the-value-of-h1-element-within-a-form-with-javascript). Just insert an element in the HTML (like an h1 tag or a p tag), give it an ID, and then replace the alert line in your code with the answer in that link for the kind of result you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get rid of the alert call and insert it into a div, span, h1, whatever. Here's an example out of the many ways:

```js
var words = ['Animals', 'Movies', 'TV Shows'];

function randomSelect() {


  var index;


  var randomValue = Math.random();


  if (randomValue < 0.5) {
    index = 0;
  }


  else if(randomValue < 0.8) {
    index = 1;
  }


  else {
    index= 2;
  }

  document.getElementById('answer').innerText = words[index]; //Get's an element of id 'answer'
}

randomSelect(); //Executes function
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="answer">
        <!-- Answer is inserted into here !-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above get's an element of id `answer` and inserts it into the element's text. This is done by accessing the `innerText` attribute of the element, which returns the text of the element. I then reassign the value to the `index`. This is quite a simple way of doing it, and I cleaned up some of the names of functions, variables.

Comment: Finally something that worked! The only thing is that it gives me the result as "0, 1 or 2". Do I have to do something different so it gives me the words (Animals, TV Shows, Movies) instead of the numbers?

Comment: Updated @DanielFregoso, it should be fully working now :)

Comment: Just one more question, is there a way to change the font (face, color, size) of the answer?

Comment: Sure, use CSS. Just target `#answer` for your rules, or you could replace the div with a span and apply it to the span

Comment: Can you please help me? D: I've only been able to change the color using <span>, but I'm still not able to change size or face. This is what I wrote:<span style="color:green" id="answer">

Comment: @DanielFregoso Here's a test [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xqm5u6sz/1/)

Comment: You can read about the font rule [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp)

Comment: How do you link the css style with the HTML <span>? Sorry if I sound like a complete noob, I just recently started on this, I'm kinda clueless.

Comment: You can use a `<style>` tag in your html or link an external file

Comment: Excuse me, is there a way to get an image as an answer instead of getting a word? Btw, your method worked perfectly :D thanks!

Comment: Sure, just change your array to include image urls (as strings) and then create an img element (can use `createElement`) with the chosen source, then append to document

Comment: Also, if you have any further questions, please refrain from asking in comments, create a new question, thanks ;)

Comment: @DanielFregoso Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s07q8zwz/) for the pictures