# how to make the increase btn in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
// 컬러리스트 선택자 변수
const year = document.querySelector("#copy .year");
const bgColor = document.querySelector("#color_bg");
const bgInnerTitle = document.querySelector("#color_bg h1");
const bgInnerText = document.querySelector("#color_bg p");


// 컬러리스트
const bgText = [
  { 
    year : year.innerText = "2017",
    color: bgInnerTitle.innerText = "Greenery",
    number: bgInnerText.innerText = "15-0343",
    bg: bgColor.style.backgroundColor = "#84bd00"
  },
  {
    year : year.innerText = "2018",
    color: bgInnerTitle.innerText = "Ultra Violet",
    number: bgInnerText.innerText = "18-3838",
    bg: bgColor.style.backgroundColor = "#5f4b8b"
  },
  {
    year : year.innerText = "2019",
    color: bgInnerTitle.innerText = "Living Coral",
    number: bgInnerText.innerText = "16-1546",
    bg: bgColor.style.backgroundColor = "#FF6D70"
  },
  {
    year : year.innerText = "2020",
    color: bgInnerTitle.innerText = "Classic Blue",
    number: bgInnerText.innerText = "19-4052",
    bg: bgColor.style.backgroundColor = "#004680"
  }
];


// 버튼
const increase = document.querySelector("#btn .increase");
const decrease = document.querySelector("#btn .decrease");

// 감소버튼
decrease.addEventListener("click", function decreaseYear(event){
  let i = 3;
  bgText[i -1];
  console.log('hi');
});

// 증가버튼
increase.addEventListener("click", function increaseYear(){
  console.log('hello');
});
```

Do you know how to make increase button work?

i wanted to make it changed when i push the button

[image]

Comment: You haven't included any of your HTML or explained how you are currently rendering the view of each year. It's going to be difficult to help without that. Also, the following code doesn't appear to do anything useful: `bgText[i -1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question right, you are trying to change all the content in the 4 tags you have selected using query selectors.
If that's what you're trying to do, I think you should edit them individually.

Like in your decrease fn:

```
i--; // initialse i outside
year.innerHTML = bgText[i].year;
bgInnerTitle.innerHTML = bgText[i].color;
...
```

Check these questions:

[html - Change the Value of h1 Element within a Form with JavaScript - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529327/change-the-value-of-h1-element-within-a-form-with-javascript)

[background color - How to use JavaScript to change div backgroundColor - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874560/how-to-use-javascript-to-change-div-backgroundcolor)

And similar questions on how to change HTML properties using JS and do then one by one.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
I made several elements.

The color changes but
-button only works once...

Comment: Please share your complete structure so that we can understand more. Like your HTML markup